# Extracting text from a table with python and lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I recently saw that another user had asked a question about extracting information from a web table [Extracting information from a webpage with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8419506/1099191). The answer from ekhumoro works great on the page that the other user asked. See below.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.uscho.com/standings/division-i-men/2011-2012/'

tree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())

for section in tree.xpath('//section[starts-with(@id, "section_")]'):
    print section.xpath('h3[1]/text()')[0]
    for row in section.xpath('table/tbody/tr'):
        cols = row.xpath('td//text()')
        print '  ', cols[0].ljust(25), ' '.join(cols[1:])
    print
```

My problem is using this code as a guide to parse this page http://www.uscho.com/rankings/d-i-mens-poll/
. Using the following changes I can only get h1 and h3 to print.

Input

```
url = 'http://www.uscho.com/rankings/d-i-mens-poll/'
tree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())

for section in tree.xpath('//section[starts-with(@id, "rankings")]'):
    print section.xpath('h1[1]/text()')[0]
    print section.xpath('h3[1]/text()')[0]
    for row in section.xpath('table/tbody/tr'):
        cols = row.xpath('td/b/text()')
        print '  ', cols[0].ljust(25), ' '.join(cols[1:])
    print
```

Output

```
USCHO.com Division I Men's Poll
December 12, 2011
```

The structure of the table seems to be the same so I'm at a loss as to why I can't use similar code. I'm just a mechanical engineer in way over my head. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lxml` is great, but if you're not familiar with `xpath`, I recommend you `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.uscho.com/rankings/d-i-mens-poll/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())

section = soup.find('section', id='rankings')
h1 = section.find('h1')
print h1.text
h3 = section.find('h3')
print h3.text
print

rows = section.find('table').findAll('tr')[1:-1]
for row in rows:
    columns = [data.text for data in row.findAll('td')[1:]]
    print '{0:20} {1:4} {2:>6} {3:>4}'.format(*columns)
```

The output for this script is:

```
USCHO.com Division I Men's Poll
December 12, 2011

Minnesota-Duluth     (49) 12-3-3  999
Minnesota                 14-5-1  901
Boston College            12-6-0  875
Ohio State           ( 1) 13-4-1  848
Merrimack                 10-2-2  844
Notre Dame                11-6-3  667
Colorado College           9-5-0  650
Western Michigan           9-4-5  647
Boston University         10-5-1  581
Ferris State              11-6-1  521
Union                      8-3-5  510
Colgate                   11-4-2  495
Cornell                    7-3-1  347
Denver                     7-6-3  329
Michigan State            10-6-2  306
Lake Superior             11-7-2  258
Massachusetts-Lowell      10-5-0  251
North Dakota               9-8-1   88
Yale                       6-5-1   69
Michigan                   9-8-3   62
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard of Beautiful Soup before. Seems much more straightforward too.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the table is slightly different, and there are columns with blank entries.

Possible `lxml` solution:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.uscho.com/rankings/d-i-mens-poll/'
tree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())

for section in tree.xpath('//section[@id="rankings"]'):
    print section.xpath('h1[1]/text()')[0],
    print section.xpath('h3[1]/text()')[0]
    print
    for row in section.xpath('table/tr[@class="even" or @class="odd"]'):
        print '%-3s %-20s %10s %10s %10s %10s' % tuple(
            ''.join(col.xpath('.//text()')) for col in row.xpath('td'))
    print
```

Output:

```
USCHO.com Division I Men's Poll December 12, 2011

1   Minnesota-Duluth           (49)     12-3-3        999          1
2   Minnesota                           14-5-1        901          2
3   Boston College                      12-6-0        875          3
4   Ohio State                 ( 1)     13-4-1        848          4
5   Merrimack                           10-2-2        844          5
6   Notre Dame                          11-6-3        667          7
7   Colorado College                     9-5-0        650          6
8   Western Michigan                     9-4-5        647          8
9   Boston University                   10-5-1        581         11
10  Ferris State                        11-6-1        521          9
11  Union                                8-3-5        510         10
12  Colgate                             11-4-2        495         12
13  Cornell                              7-3-1        347         16
14  Denver                               7-6-3        329         13
15  Michigan State                      10-6-2        306         14
16  Lake Superior                       11-7-2        258         15
17  Massachusetts-Lowell                10-5-0        251         18
18  North Dakota                         9-8-1         88         19
19  Yale                                 6-5-1         69         17
20  Michigan                             9-8-3         62         NR
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'table/tbody/tr'` by `'table/tr'`.

Comment: I got a whole bunch of other stuff when I did that. I got a lot of tabular data except for the data in question. I wonder why that happ but it is kinda puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

Though this answer is old, it still comes up on the web.

I'd like another (more straightforward and uptodate) option. It adds up more dependancies though (pandas & tabulate (which is a dependancy to the to_markdown method))...

Unfortunatelly, I think the webpage associated to the url used in this question has changed quite a lot since then (the table is now generated from javascript and is not in the source code anymore). So I'll skip to this [url](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) instead for practical purpose.

```
from lxml import etree, html
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'
r = requests.get(url)

#If you want to get a specific table, procede as follow :

tree_html = html.fromstring(r.content)
first_table = tree_html.xpath(".//table")[0]
df = pd.read_html(etree.tostring(table))[0]
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Output :

```
|    | Tag        | Description                                                             |
|---:|:-----------|:------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | <table>    | Defines a table                                                         |
|  1 | <th>       | Defines a header cell in a table                                        |
|  2 | <tr>       | Defines a row in a table                                                |
|  3 | <td>       | Defines a cell in a table                                               |
|  4 | <caption>  | Defines a table caption                                                 |
|  5 | <colgroup> | Specifies a group of one or more columns in a table for formatting      |
|  6 | <col>      | Specifies column properties for each column within a <colgroup> element |
|  7 | <thead>    | Groups the header content in a table                                    |
|  8 | <tbody>    | Groups the body content in a table                                      |
|  9 | <tfoot>    | Groups the footer content in a table                                    |
```

But you can also get all tables in one shot, this way :

```
list_tables = pd.read_html(r.content)
for table in list_table:
  print(table.to_markdown()+'\n')
```

Output :

```
|    | Company                      | Contact          | Country   |
|---:|:-----------------------------|:-----------------|:----------|
|  0 | Alfreds Futterkiste          | Maria Anders     | Germany   |
|  1 | Centro comercial Moctezuma   | Francisco Chang  | Mexico    |
|  2 | Ernst Handel                 | Roland Mendel    | Austria   |
|  3 | Island Trading               | Helen Bennett    | UK        |
|  4 | Laughing Bacchus Winecellars | Yoshi Tannamuri  | Canada    |
|  5 | Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti | Giovanni Rovelli | Italy     |

|    | Tag        | Description                                                             |
|---:|:-----------|:------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | <table>    | Defines a table                                                         |
|  1 | <th>       | Defines a header cell in a table                                        |
|  2 | <tr>       | Defines a row in a table                                                |
|  3 | <td>       | Defines a cell in a table                                               |
|  4 | <caption>  | Defines a table caption                                                 |
|  5 | <colgroup> | Specifies a group of one or more columns in a table for formatting      |
|  6 | <col>      | Specifies column properties for each column within a <colgroup> element |
|  7 | <thead>    | Groups the header content in a table                                    |
|  8 | <tbody>    | Groups the body content in a table                                      |
|  9 | <tfoot>    | Groups the footer content in a table                                    |
```